# command line SMTP client such as cleancode's email

Tags: command-line, email, smtp

I'm looking for a command line like [cleancode's email program](http://www.cleancode.org/projects/email) which would allow me to send emails from the command line without setting an MTA (and would allow me to use separate accounts for each users, without touching the MTA's configuration).

Is there a PPA with cleancode's email program? Is there other similar program which is packaged with ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) fit your needs? It means you can run SMTP commands locally without running a full SMTP server. msmtp will just forward it to a SMTP server and is configured by a file in your home directory, so different users can have different configurations.

msmtp has been in the ubuntu repositories for a few years now.

Comment: Looks good. A simple MTA which does just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

So you want an MTA, without setting up an MTA?

I use an ssh tip http://dabase.com/e/01087 when I'm in a hurry and it gets around firewalls that block outgoing mail.

Comment: Yes, like in every sane GUI MUA. I want to send email through gmail's SMTP, but the other user wants it through Yahoo's. And both should be able to change their mind without administrator interface. Except, I don't want the MTA to gobble memory all day long when I actually use it only twice a day. Thus I want a full command line SMTP client like cleancode's is exactly what I want. I just rather to have something in the official distribution than compile it on my own.